# VBA to filter values based on Two Criteria wherein Header column keeps on changing

Tags: vba, excel, filter, macros

In VBA i've recorded below code wherein, Col E = "Currency" & Col B = "Policy"..

What it should do is..

1. Both the column header Currency & Policy keeps on changing so they should be automatically find by there names..
2. Col Currency should filter as "USD" & Col Policy should filter as "Willis PCard" than the filtered result should be copied to new sheet naming as "P Card - "
3. Col Currency should filter as "USD" & Col Policy should filter as "Willis" & "Willis Re" & both should be copied to new sheet naming as "US -"

`

```
Sub Filter()    
'
' Filter Macro
'
'

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$337").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="USD"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$337").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
"Willis PCard"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "P Card - "
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("ProcessorReportsList").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$337").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Willis" _
, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Willis RE"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$337").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="<>"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "US on Hold - "
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("ProcessorReportsList").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$337").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="="
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "US - "
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("US on Hold - ").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("P Card - ").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("ProcessorReportsList").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

However, the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tROlq.png) seems unexpected

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you have recorded the whole working step I am going to take a shot in the dark and say you are new to VBA? If so I do recommend looking at some VBA guides/courses [http://www.homeandlearn.org/]  is a good site to start at, also on this site code review will be good as it is for code that already works but you are wanting to improve it(NOTE - only for working code use code review), as you improve I ope you will help others on this site and other sites!

Answer (score 0):

See a cleaner way of performing what you desire below. Note that it is only for USD and "Willie PCard", you will need to edit it for any other AutoFilter etc.

```
 Sub FilterAndCopy()

      Dim DataWorkBook As Workbook
      Set DataWorkBook = ThisWorkbook

      Dim DataWorkSheet As Worksheet
      Set DataWorkSheet = DataWorkBook.Sheets("ProcessorReportList")

      Dim FirstRowRange As Range
      Dim CurrencyColumn As Long
      Dim PolicyColumn As Long

      Set FirstRowRange = DataWorkSheet.Rows(1).Find("Currency")
      CurrencyColumn = FirstRowRange.Column

      Set FirstRowRange = DataWorkSheet.Rows(1).Find("Policy")
      PolicyColumn = FirstRowRange.Column

      FirstRowRange.AutoFilter Field:=CurrencyColumn, Criteria1:="USD"
      FirstRowRange.AutoFilter Field:=PolicyColumn, Criteria1:="Willis PCard"

      DataWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy

      Dim PCard9Sheet As Worksheet
      Set PCard9Sheet = DataWorkBook.Sheets.Add(After:=DataWorkBook.Sheets("ProcessorReportList"))
      PCard9Sheet.Name = "P Card - 9"

      PCard9Sheet.Paste

 End Sub
```